# Set up only one unit test in requiere.context test.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I am trying to set up a single spec in the required context as follows:

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /my-element.component\.spec\.ts$/);
```

But it is not finding any spec in that path, however if I leave the context as default, it finds it!

DEFAULT: `const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);`

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you just miss to escape the dot in front of `component`?

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /my-element\.component\.spec\.ts$/);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it, with the same result, however, I don't think it's necessary to escape the dots in a regular expression.

Comment: Some maybe dumb questions: Is the name of the spec file you want to run exactly `my-element.component.spec.ts`? Did you restart karma after changing the `test.ts`? About escaping the dots: if you do not escape them, they mean "any character". You are right, in this case it does not change anything, because also "dot" is "any character". But without escaping also a file named `my-elementXcomponent.spec.ts` would match the pattern.